# Compiling Mono from Visual Studio with sgen support

Tags: visual-studio, mono, garbage-collection, sgen

I have a Mono binary obtained from a build with Visual Studio. The option --gc=sgen used to enable sgen garbage collector is not available:

```
Error: --gc=<NAME> option not supported on this platform.
```

How to enable this option ? Is there any define ?

Comment: sry I misunderstood the question. I only have experience in building mono from source on linux.

Comment: The last I heard, there was no Windows port of sgen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sgen GC will be available on windows starting from the next mono releases, 2.11/2.12 (though not necessarily in the VS build).